# How to make all fields required in form

Tags: angular

I am working on my Angular2 project. I have developed a form and I want to make  all the fields required. I tried to make Title required but its not showing required output. I am not getting whats going wrong. Please, guide me in right direction.

```html
# product-form.component.html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input #title="ngModel" ngModel name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
         Title is required. 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
      <input ngModel name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
        {{ c.name }}
      </option>  
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageUrl">image URL</label>
    <input ngModel name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" type="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>  
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you can just use [required] HTML 5 in the inputs to mark them as required

Comment: I got the mistake just add "required" attribute in the input field. Hope this will also work for other developers. Thank you.

Comment: ya @Mike Tung I got the mistake Thank you to you too.

Answer (score 0):

afaik just add required to the inputs like this

```html
product-form.component.html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input required #title="ngModel" ngModel name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
     <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
         Title is required. 
    </div>
   </div>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <label for="price">Price</label>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
     <input required ngModel name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="category">Category</label>
  <select ngModel name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
      {{ c.name }}
  </option>  
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="imageUrl">image URL</label>
      <input required ngModel name="imageUrl" id="imageUrl" type="imageUrl" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>  
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </form>
```

but I prefer using reactive forms.. so in you component javascript file create a form

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(formbuilder: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInIt(){
    this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
        title: new FormControl('', [validators.Required])
    })
}
```

then in the template do like

```html
product-form.component.html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input [formControlName]="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control">
   </div>
</form>
```

That way is better IMO

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in the comments OP had to use HTML5 [required] attribute to input tags in order to set them as required.